# Using MPI communication with containerized applications

Tags: mpi, openmpi, singularity-container, pmix

I've successfully executed a program on my cluster using

```
mpirun -np 1 ./my_program
```

I've containerized `my_program` using Singularity and produced `my_program.simg`. The container also includes the same version of OpenMPI as the host. I'd like to have nodes in my cluster execute the Singularity container, so I tried:

```
mpirun -np 1 \
    singularity run my_program.simg
```

However, this fails:

```
[pn111:395108] PMIX ERROR: NOT-FOUND in file ../../../../../../../openmpi-3.1.3/opal/mca/pmix/pmix2x/pmix/src/server/pmix_server_ops.c at line 1865
[pn111:395108] PMIX ERROR: NOT-FOUND in file ../../../../../../../openmpi-3.1.3/opal/mca/pmix/pmix2x/pmix/src/server/pmix_server_ops.c at line 1865
[pn111:395108] PMIX ERROR: NOT-FOUND in file ../../../../../../../openmpi-3.1.3/opal/mca/pmix/pmix2x/pmix/src/server/pmix_server_ops.c at line 1865
```

I'm assuming that I need to expose something to the container so it knows how to speak to the MPI universe. Is there a socket I need to bind into the container, or an environment variable I need to set, or something like that?

The [Singularity documentation](https://www.sylabs.io/guides/2.5/user-guide/introduction.html#compatibility-with-standard-work-flows-pipes-and-io) suggests there's nothing extra to do.

[This GitHub issue](https://github.com/sylabs/singularity/issues/876) may have good advice, which I will try.

Comment: The `PMIx` used outside of the container (e.g. `mpirun`) must be compatible with the one used inside the container (e.g. `a.out`). Which `PMIx` and Open MPI versions are you running both inside and outside the container ?

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet I think that's on the right track. I synchronized the versions and now have a different PMIX error.

Comment: I have the same issue. Have you been able to resolve it?

Comment: @mneuner No, it seemed too complicated unfortunately.

Comment: Alright thanks. My application/cointainer works well with OpenMPI 2.1.1, but I get exactly the same warning with OpenMPI 3.1.3. €: Of course always the same version inside/outside the cointainer!